# Instalar una fuente en Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular

Buenas tardes estoy intentando instalar una fuente en mi proyecto de Angular 8 ya la descargue y la guarde en la carpeta de assets pero no encuentro como insertarla en el proyecto.

encontre esto:

```
   @font-face {
  font-family: lato;
  src: url(assets/font/Lato.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

pero no se en que parte insertarlo

Comment: https://medium.com/@aditya_tyagi/import-fonts-in-an-angular-app-the-easy-right-way-ae9e99cab551

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878988/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas poner tus fuentes en la carpeta de 'assets' (también puedes crear una sub-carpeta de fuentes dentro de la de assets) y referirte a ella en el Styles:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: lato;
  src: url(assets/font/Lato.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Una vez hecho, tú puedes llamar a las fuentes así:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'lato', 'arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Puedes poner `@font-face` en tu definición global de  `styles.css` o `styles.scss` y llamarlas desde cualquier lugar de la aplicación - siempre que tú componente tenga un CSS/SCSS específico. `styles.css` o `styles.scss` está ya definido en `angular-cli.json`. Si tú buscas crear un CSS/SCSS fichero diferente, y declararlo en el angular-cli.json junto con el `styles.css` o `styles.scss` ponlo así :

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "fonts.css"
],
```